# Is the "limit function" a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=g(x_0)\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is $g$ a continuous function?

Comment: Have you researched on the web for Continous functions. Here is a good link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function

Comment: By considering the constant sequence you directly have $f=g$ and then you have the definition of continuous

Comment: @Listing: Constant sequences (and, more generally, sequences $(x_n')$ such that $x_n' = x_0$ for some $n$) are likely to be excluded. There was some discussion about this definition some time ago, although I don't remember in which topic. Hence, the arguments one has to use are more sophisticated, and $f$ may no be continuous.

Comment: See ALso: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/is-there-a-function-with-a-removable-discontinuity-at-every-point

Comment: That is in fact the very definition of continuous!

Answer (score 5):

Fix an $x_0$ and let an  $\epsilon>0$ be given. We have to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$ as soon as $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

By assumption on $f$ and $g$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|f(x)-g(x_0)|<{\epsilon\over2}\qquad \bigl(0<|x-x_0|<\delta\bigr)\ .$$
Consider now an arbitrary $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$. There is a $\delta'>0$ such that
$$|f(x')-g(x)|<{\epsilon\over2}\qquad \bigl(0<|x'-x|<\delta'\bigr)\ .$$
The open set $$S:=\ ]x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta[\ \cap\ ]x-\delta',x+\delta'[\ \ \setminus\{x_0,x\}$$
is nonempty; therefore we may take a point $x'\in S$ and then have
$$|g(x)-g(x_0)|<|g(x)-f(x')|+|f(x')-g(x_0)|<{\epsilon\over2}+{\epsilon\over2}=\epsilon\ .$$

Answer (score 4):

Take $\varepsilon>0$.

By definition of the limit (assuming the limit in the statement is well defined, otherwise the question has no meaning) there exists some $\delta>0$ such that on the *punctured* interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus\{x_0\}$ we get $|f(x)-g(x_0)|<\varepsilon/2$. In particular every $g(x)$ on this interval has to be strictly within $\varepsilon$ of $g(x_0)$, since values of $f$ are bounded to within $\varepsilon/2$ of $g(x_0)$ so any limit on values of $f$ (which define $g$) will also subsequently be bounded to within $\varepsilon$, which proves continuity of $g$.

Note that this isn't based on the continuity of $f$, which is not required for $g$ to be continuous, for example $f$ can contain infinitely many isolated removable discontinuities, and $g$ is still happily continuous.

Comment: A concrete example of a discontinuous $f$ is [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) -- for which $g$ is identically zero.

Comment: There is something missing here. The statement "In particular every $g(x)$ on this interval has to be strictly within $\varepsilon$ of $g(x_0)\ $" needs clarification.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, how's that for clarification?